# How to prevent pulling of just created docker image

Tags: concourse

```
resources:
- name: git-clone-resource
  type: git
  source:
    branch: master
    uri: https://github.com/drahnr/oregano.git
- name: oregano-test-ubuntu
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: quay.io/ratpoison/oregano-test-ubuntu
    username: {{quay-username}}
    password: {{quay-password}}

jobs:
  - name: build-docker-image-fedora
    public: true
    plan:
      - get: git-clone-resource
        trigger: true
      - put: oregano-test-fedora
        params:
          cache: true
          tag_as_latest: true
          build: git-clone-resource/.concourse/fedora

  - name: compile
    public: true
    plan:
    - get: git-clone-resource
      trigger: true
      passed: [build-docker-image-fedora]
    - task: compile
      image: oregano-test-fedora
      config:
        platform: linux
        inputs:
        - name: git-clone-resource
        run:
          path: xvfb-run
          args: ["./waf", "configure", "debug", "--prefix=/tmp", "install"]
          dir: "git-clone-resource"
```

The issue there is, despite the direct `image` declaration, `oregano-test-fedora` is still being pulled from the quay.io registry.

I followed the approach outlined in the official docs at https://concourse-ci.org/task-step.html#task-image

How can I achieve that the local image is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `image` that's referencing a resource that hasn't been `get` yet. Different jobs do not share inputs/outputs, any passing of artifacts between them must happen by using resources (backed by third parties).

Not only that, but the use of `image` requires an image that was the result of a `get`, not a put. This means that the docker image that was pushed has to be retrieved via `get`, first. There's no way to only use a "locally cached" version, this must hit `quay.io`, by design.

Answer (score 1):

`oregano-test-fedora` is being pulled from your registry because of the `put` in job `build-docker-image-fedora`. You can add a `skip_download` to the `put` to avoid the pull.

Comment: But I want to use that image afterwards in the same pipeline? Is that still possible when using `skip_download`, the documentation suggests other.

Comment: No, you cannot skip_download and then use the image.